# jqgrid retrieve data of cell and manipulate it

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to retrieve from a `dataEvents` event the value the user entered. I want to only allow the numbers 0-24 and if the user inserts a number like 4,5 (german writing) I want to replace the "," with a ".". Thus convert "4,5" to "4.5".

But I'm struggling with getting the data the user entered. The method I'm using always returns blank.

```
colModel:[
    {name:'sum',index:'sum', width:45, editable: true, sortable:false,
     editoptions: { dataEvents: [ 
                        {
                            type: 'keypress', // keydown
                            fn: function(e) {
                                // console.log('keypress');
                                var v=$(e.target).text();
                                alert(v); // v is empty.
                                //reset the target value, actually I want to replace
                                // enter code here a comma with a point
                                // only allow the numbers 0 - 24
                            }
                        }
                    ] 
                  }
    },
],
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do replacement of ',' to '.' better inside of 'keyup' event handler with the following

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/,'.'));
```

So you can use following `dataEvents`

```
dataEvents: [
    {
        type: 'keyup',
        fn: function(e) {
            var oldVal = $(this).val();
            var newVal = oldVal.replace(/,/,'.');
            if (oldVal !== newVal) {
                $(this).val(newVal);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'keypress',
        fn: function(e) {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode; // to support all browsers
            if((key < 48 || key > 57) &&   // if non digit
               key !== 46 && key !== 44 && key !== 8 && // and not . or , or backspace
               key !== 37 && key !== 39) { // arrow left and arrow right
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
]
```

On [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ToolbarSearchReplaceKey.htm) you can see the results live. The only disadvantage which I see in the example is following: if you will try to type comma **in the middle of the text**, the cursor position (caret) will be changed to the end of  the input after the replacement comma to point. Probably it is not a real problem in your case. It you do want to save the cursor position you should probably do this 
`document.selection` using for IE or `.selectionStart` and `.selectionEnd` for Firefox.

**UPDATED**: I fixed the problem with the usage of `e.keyCode` inside of `keypress` event in the Firefox. I follows the information from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) and use now `e.charCode || e.keyCode` instead of `e.keyCode`. The above code and the demo are fixed now.

Comment: Oleg, this is awesome! I will try it in a moment, but the live demo (wow getting a live demo) is already exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thank you Oleg. It works perfectly fine! You saved my weekend ;-)

Comment: @Oleg: I just recognized that the user is not able to insert a number in the cell if using firefox, whereas in chrome it works. Do you have an idea how to circumvent this problem!?

Comment: @Tom Tom: I will try to look at the problem tomorrow.

Comment: @Tom Tom: I found the reason of the problem in Firefox which you described and fixed the code. Best regards.

Comment: @Oleg: wow.. cross-browser programming is still hard work. funny enough, in firefox I can now not press the backspace button.. whereas it works in IE and chrome.

Comment: @Tom Tom: I updated the code one more time. I included `&& key !== 8` in the `if`.

Comment: @Tom Tom: I added also code for arrow left and arrow right. You can easy modify the code to allow more keys.