# Events inside JqGrid Add Form

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to add events inside Add Form in jqgrid. Say For example in below Add form, i want to set **size avg** value based on the value from **size** i enter. (Here 3/6). i don't want to set the value in **onSubmit** event but before selecting **Size Rem**

[image]

```js
{name:'size', index:'size', width:80, align:'right', hidden: false, editable:true},  
{name:'sizeavg', index:'sizeavg', width:80, align:'right', editable:true, hidden: false}, 
{name:'sizerem', index:'sizerem', width:80, align:'right', editable:true, hidden: false, 
    edittype:'select',align:'left',
    editoptions:{value:{F:'F',S:'S',FS:'F/S',NA:'Double Butt'}},
},
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jqGrid provides you many ways to implement any scenario which you need. First of all you need understand that form editing, which you use now, assigns `id` attribute on every input field in the form. The value of `id` attribute is equal to the value of `name` property of the column in `colModel`. So to access `sizeavg` input field for example you can use `$("#sizeavg").val()`. It gives you simple way to modify the field on some conditions or in case of some event.

To catch an event you need to bind it to the corresponding input field. One way to do this is to use `dataEvents` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). You can find examples of event binding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407958/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935) and many other answers.

So you can bind `change`, `focusout`, `keydown` or some other event to `size` or `sizerem` columns. You can get the current values using `$("#size").val()` and `$("#sizerem option:selected").val()` and then if required modify the value of `sizeavg` using `$("#sizeavg").val("new nalue")`.